# Place a button in UITableView footer and make the UITableViewCell not be under the footer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So, I have implemented this method to add a footer to my table view:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 60;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now, you see, there are two problems:

1) I would like to add a button inside the table view footer but when I drag a button control in the storyboard, it does not work. How to add a button there?

2) As you can see, the footer is transparent and there is a table view cell visible under it. I would like there to be no cells under the footer (so the last visible cell would be the one above the footer). Second, I would like the footer not to be transparent.

I am using Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is a delegate method. Try instead to access [sectionFooterHeight](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/sectionFooterHeight) property of your table.

To add a button you may consider adding a custom view to your footer. You can access [tableFooterView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView) and assign a custom view to it.

Comment: I did that. I used sectionFooterHeight and now the footer does not appear at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to create a footer view for table

```
- (UIView *) createViewForTableFooter
{
    CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60);
    UIView *tableFooter = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect] autorelease];
    tableFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton* verifyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [verifyButton setTitle:WNLocalizedString(@"Verify",@"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [verifyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [verifyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(verifyBtnTapped:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    verifyButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [verifyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 88, 37)];
    }else {
        [verifyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 37)];
    }
    [tableFooter addSubview:verifyButton];

    return tableFooter;
}
```

And use this function like this in your viewDidLoad method

```
yourTableObjectName.tableFooterView = [self createViewForTableFooter];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use tableView:viewForFooterInSection: method to add button to the footer

Answer (score 1):

increase contente size of tableviews bottom

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.tableView.contentInset;
contentInset.bottom = 50.0f; // **the height of the footer**
self.tableView.contentInset = contentInset;
```